# submit form from one model to another view in Yii

Tags: yii

How do I post from one controller into another view?

I have a `Review` model and a `Product` model. The `Review` form is displayed in the `Product` view through a widget, but how do I submit the form itself? Right now, it doesn't do anything. I can submit through review/create, but not through the `Product` View.

Or am i suppose to do the post in the widget?

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us a bit more. How are you rendering that form exactly? Through which widget?

Comment: post the view that contains the form, and your controller

Comment: post your code related to view and controller/action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it if you put code like below on **components/ReviewWidget.php** . I supposed you have Review as model and its respective controller and views file on default locations.

```
<?php

class ReviewWidget extends CWidget{
    public function init() {
        return parent::init();
    }
    public function run(){
        $model = new Review;

        if (isset($_POST['Review'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Review'];
            $model->save();
        }
        $this->renderFile(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.review'). '/_form.php',array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
}
```

Then, call above widget on any where on view like below ,

```
<?php  $this->widget('ReviewWidget'); ?>
```

It will handle item creation only. You have to create code  to item update by yourself.

Comment: I realized I started off with cactiveform in the widget. But this works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you must use function renderPartial

```
$this->renderPartial('//views/reviw/_form',array('data' => $data ) );
```

First argument of this function is used to determine which view to use:

> - absolute view within a module: the view name starts with a single    slash '/'. In this case, the view will be searched for under the
>     currently active module's view path. If there is no active module,
>     the view will be searched for under the application's view path.
> - absolute view within the application: the view name starts with    double slashes '//'. In this case, the view will be searched for
>     under the application's view path. This syntax has been available
>     since version 1.1.3.
> - aliased view: the view name contains dots and    refers to a path alias. The view file is determined by calling
>     YiiBase::getPathOfAlias(). Note that aliased views cannot be themed
>     because they can refer to a view file located at arbitrary places.
> - relative view: otherwise. Relative views will be searched for under the currently active     controller's view path.

Also you can use this function in your views. But the most convenient way to reuse views is to create widgets.